# Pybind: Is it possible to inform Python about the names of the arguments for constructors?

Tags: python, constructor, anaconda, spyder, pybind11

In Pybind it is possible to inform Python about the names of the arguments for **functions**:

```
m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers",
  py::arg("i"), py::arg("j"));
```

(http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#keyword-arguments)

Is there something similar for **constructors**? Spyder (Anaconda) already shows the input arguments of functions by default, but for constructors the "help" only shows: (*args, **kwargs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in exactly the same way as it is for member functions or functions :)

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x, int y) {}
    void bar(int a, int b) {}
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(cpp_module, m) {
    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<int, int>(), py::arg("x"), py::arg("y"))
        .def("bar", &Foo::bar, py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"));
}
```

As far as I can see, there is no real difference between using `py::arg` for functions, member functions or constructors, it works in the same way (including default values etc).

---

Overloading a function (including the constructor) is an interesting case. Since Python has no similar overloading mechanism, this is handled by pybind11. `help()` will still work, but it'll show something like this:

```
__init__(...)
    __init__(*args, **kwargs)
    Overloaded function.

    1. __init__(self: some_cpp.Foo, x: int, y: int) -> None

    2. __init__(self: some_cpp.Foo) -> None
```

As you can see, `__init__` itself takes `(*args, **kwargs)` and this will be what is autocompleted by most IDE's. A way around this would be to use static methods as constructors, this way you can give each constructors a unique name so Python knows about this. For example, `Foo Foo::from_ints(int x, int y)` and `Foo Foo::from_string(std::string s)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your code and it does work but only if there is only one constructor. Most of the time I have a standard constructor without inputs and one with inputs. Do you know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: `py::init<...>()` works just like the "name" of the method representing the constructor (like `__init__` in Python), so I don't really know where it could go wrong. Also, why would you want argument names for a constructor without arguments (if that is what you mean with "without inputs")?

Comment: I tried it for one object named Box. I have one constructor py::init<>() without arguments and one with a vector with doubles as input arguments. When I write "Box(" in spyder (anaconda) the "help" only shows: (*args, **kwargs). I would like to have the hint input: "vector<double>", but this only works if I delete the constructor without arguments..

Comment: I have a function overload where one function is defined twice and the help in spyder shows both options.. this functionality would be perfect for constructors as well..

Comment: @thzu What you describe is not directly possible I fear. See my edits. I can't help you with spyder, for that you'll need a separate question.

Comment: yes, the help function works.. the automatic help for normal functions is certainly prettier, but that' will do.